# gtk-builder-convert Error

Tags: gtk, c, glade

I am doing the tutorial in the link http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html

When I run the gtk-builder-convert tutorial.glade tutorial.xml I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 799, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
    File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 787, in main
    conv.parse_file(input_filename)
    File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 162, in parse_file
    self._parse()
    File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 234, in _parse
    assert glade_iface, ("Badly formed XML, there is "

    AssertionError: Badly formed XML, there is no <glade-interface> tag.
```

the glade file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes">GTK+ Text Editor</property>
        <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
        <child>
            <placeholder/>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Note: the glade file was generated using Glade 3.14.0 in ubuntu 12.10

Comment: if I manually change the tag <interface> to <glade-interface> in the glade file and then run the command gtk-builder-convert then the xml file is generated. I still would like to know why auto generated tag did not work

Answer (score 2):

The last time I programmed in Glade/GTK, it didn't require "gtk-builder-convert". The .glade file that glade provides is itself xml file you need. Just program your code as if you already have converted the file to .xml (btw, i'm using glade 3.12.1). As:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *object, gpointer user_data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "ui.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (on_window_destroy), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show (window);       
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```